# NSString from NSData is null?

Tags: objective-c

I am getting data from server , the NSData is good and gives a number in bytes. 
the NSString is null: (the second log)

```
NSData *stringOfData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [data length])];
NSString *finalData = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringOfData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

NSLog(@"RECIEVED FROM SERVER:%@",stringOfData); //is ok
NSLog(@"RECIEVED :%@",finalData); //is null

RECIEVED FROM SERVER:<0b000000 02000000 03000000 453242>
RECIEVED :
```

Whats wrong here ?
I was trying everything and somehow it always null . .

**EDIT:** the data is bytes that i am getting from the server .
it suppose to be an int number, but i wanted to show it as string ..
i was trying other kind of coding,but still null ..

Comment: What does the `subdataWithRange` call do?  It appears to return the same amount of data as the original object?  Also  how is `0b000000 02000000 03000000 453242` in any way a "string"?

Comment: "stringOfData" it contains what? i mean what type of data?

Comment: Did you try any other encoding like NSASCIIStringEncoding?

Comment: thanks both . see my edit. maybe the fact that it is an integer is whats wrong here. i have to check my self again .

Comment: I don’t think `finalData` in `nil`. If it were, your `NSLog` call would output “RECIEVED :(null)”. Most likely it’s the empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data contains integers, then loading the raw data into an NSString won't do what you want. Perhaps you want something more like this:

```
int *i = (int *)data.bytes;
NSLog(@"RECIEVED :%d, %d, %d, %d", i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3]);
```

You might also find yourself having to deal with byte order issues. If so, this might help:

```
NSLog(@"RECIEVED :%d, %d, %d", ntohl(i[0]), ntohl(i[1]), ntohl(i[2]), ntohl(i[3]));
```

Comment: Note that you should use the fixed-size integer types (like `uint32_t`) instead of `int` since you’re supposed to know how many bits make up each of the integers in your data (whereas the definition of `int` might vary depending on which platform you’re on).